# Highcharts - show only selected points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to have a line that only shows points that are selected (they will actually be pre-selected).

In this example - http://jsfiddle.net/jhG8j/ - you can show selected points when you click the button, but I can only get it to work if all the other points are already shown (marker:enabled).  Is there a way to start off with just a plain line, and then only show the selected points?

Here is the relevant code from jsfiddle:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }  
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

// button handler
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    i = 0;
$('#button').click(function() {

    if (i == chart.series[0].data.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    chart.series[0].data[i].select(true, true);
    i++;
});
```

});

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I want a chart that has 25 datapoints on it, but only 3 points that show as selected, i.e. they stick out from the line.  The rest of the line should be smooth.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You can still hover over the smooth line and get information right?

Comment: yes, that would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get away with this by creating two separate series. In order to align your series to look like they are one line chart, you'd need to add a few nulls into your data, and ensure that the last data point of the first series is the first data point of the following series.

Using the jsfiddle you provided, updated code is below:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        plotOptions: {
            line: {

            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4] ,
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            } ,
            color: '#000000'
        },{
            data: [null, null , 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]  ,
            marker: {
                enabled: false ,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false   
                    } ,
                    states: {
                        select: false   
                    }
                }
            },
            color: '#000000'
        }]
    });

    // button handler
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        i = 0;
    $('#button').click(function() {

        if (i == chart.series[0].data.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        chart.series[0].data[i].select(true, true);
        i++;
    });
});
```